# Change Authorized Attribute '/Account/Login' to own Login path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, authorization

I have `AuthController.cs` and to routes:

`auth/login` - login page,
`auth/register` - register page.

Also I have another controller - `ClientController.cs` - which has `[Authorized]` attribute.
When I trying to reach client's page, I automatically redirects to `Account/Login` but its not correct login path.

**Question:** how to change `[Authorized]` attribute redirect path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually... we need to understand the concept of [Authentication Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#authentication-scheme) to get it work right... but for the sake of simplicity, I'll assume you are just using the default configuration. Try this:

```
services.AddAuthentication("YourSchemeName").AddCookie("YourSchemeName",
                config =>
                {
                    config.Cookie.Name = "YourCookieName";
                    config.LoginPath = "/auth/login";
                });
```

Replace `.AddCookie()` with the kind of Authentication method that you're using (like Jwt or some custom AuthenticationHandler would be `.AddScheme<>()`)

Comment: But, I'm using Identity. Does this work with Identity?

Comment: Yes, It does... I don't know if you are aiming at [Identity Server](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) or [Microsoft Identity platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/), but either way, it works

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to explicitly specify the DefaultAuthenticateScheme.

```
.AddAuthentication (options => {
  options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
```

instead of

```
.AddAuthentication (CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```